# How do I solve Installation of PyDictionary error?

Tags: django

I am trying to build a simple word search dictionary using django and when I install pyDictinary which is a django package I get this error: 'python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.'. How can I solve this, or how other way can I get to use the package? I am made to know that pip has no problem.

I run "pip install pyDictionary" on vscode terminal

Comment: Please share your full error message.